# Getting undefined method `each' for #<Post:0xb5d0df30> at index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Trying out ruby, i just asked a question but here's another, getting undefined method `each' for # and i tried a lot of stuff

```
<h1>This is the index page</h1>
<p>I need to get the new action running!</p>
<%= link_to 'My Blog', controller: 'posts' %>
</br>
<%= link_to 'New post', new_post_path %>

<h1>Listing posts</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Text</th>
  </tr>

  <% @posts.each do |post| %>  ///<----ERROR HERE!
    <tr>
      <td><%= posts.title %></td>
      <td><%= posts.description %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', posts_path(posts) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_posts_path(posts) %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

This is my controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.new
  end

  def edit
    @posts = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
  @posts = Post.find(params[:id])

  if @posts.update(posts_params)
    redirect_to @posts
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

  def new
    @posts = Post.new
  end

  def create
      @posts = Post.new(posts_params)
    if @posts.save
        redirect_to @post
    else
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @posts = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
  def posts_params
    params.require(:posts).permit(:title, :description)
  end


end
```

I'm pretty sure i changed eveything to be matching like @posts from @post, i would appreciate if someone could help me again, i've tried looking for an answer but not getting luck, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller under the index do:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
end
```

Then in your view after your each do refer to the variable as `post`, not `posts`.

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= post.title %></td>
    <td><%= post.description %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', post_path(post) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Are you doing Post.all or Post.new in the index?

Answer (score 1):

Modify the index method in your controller to the following:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
end
```

`Post.new` returns a single (empty) objet, the `each` method expects an `enumerable` (array, hash, collection,...), hence the error.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly, this was driving me crazy i knew it was a simple thing but i couldn't find it, thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Your @posts instance variable is pointing to a new post record instead of a collection of posts. You need an array to iterate over instead of a single post.

Comment: and how do i do that ? sorry for being noob

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call `.each` on an object, that object has to be made up of a *collection* of data (even if the "collection" has one element).

You're calling `Post.new` - meaning the `.each` method is going to return an exception that it cannot cycle through  the expected collection.

You need to do the following:

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @posts = Post.all
   end
end
```

This should get your code working.